# Oracle SQL - TO_NUMBER RN Format_model

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert some Roman numerals into numbers. There are some quite complex methods, but I wonder whether it's possible to use TO_NUMBER fuction.

There's a 'RN' format, it works well other way round, say:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR('1998', 'RN')
FROM DUAL;
```

However this won't work:

```
SELECT
TO_NUMBER('MCMXCVIII', 'RN')
FROM DUAL;
```

Any ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the function "TO_NUMBER" o "TO_CHAR" for convert a roman number to decimal, but today there is a algorithm for do it.
This algorithm use CTE / recursive subquery.

For each character, starting from the RIGHT (lowest value Roman numeral):

1.- Convert the character into the value it represents

2.- If the character’s value is greater than or equal to the previous one, add the value to the running total

3.- If character’s value is less than the previous one, subtract the value from the running total

Below, I leave you the url the documentation and the script.

References:
http://rdbms-insight.com/wp/2015/roman-numerals-to-decimal-in-sql/
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CESOH7H2D4O88XLW60330Q3L9.html

I hope to help you :)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know whether there is there any use of RN format in TO_NUMBER function?